# vSphere Install Best Practice

Tags: installation, vmware-vsphere

can anyone detail or supply documentation on best practice for upgading from ESX 3.5/VC 2.5 to vSphere, including any gotchas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the link grub posted. There is also a good webcast [How to Upgrade from VMware Infrastructure 3 to VMware vSphere 4](http://www.vmware.com/a/webcasts/details/248) and once you have upgraded [Do I Upgrade to VMware Virtual Hardware Version 7?](http://www.simonlong.co.uk/blog/2010/02/10/do-i-upgrade-to-vmware-virtual-hardware-version-7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a upgrade guide here:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009039